# Update pandas column names with replace chain not working properly

Tags: python, pandas

We have the following column names:

```
our_df.columns
Index(['Rank', 'Album', 'Artist', 'Label', 'Label Description',
       'Peak Position', 'Last Week Rank', 'Last 2 Week Rank', 'Weeks On Chart',
       'TW Total Activity', '% CHG', 'LW Total Activity', 'TW Album Sales',
       'TW Song Sales', 'TW TEA', 'TW Audio Streaming Activity',
       'TW Video Streaming Activity', 'TW Total SEA (Audio + Video)', 'ATD'],
      dtype='object')
```

And we'd like to do something like this:

```
our_df.columns.str.replace(' ','_').replace('.', '').replace('+/-','plus_minus').lower()
```

...where we first make all of the replacements, and then convert everything to lowercase. However, this is failing with the error `'Index' object has no attribute 'replace'`. We've updated this to

```
our_df.columns.str.replace(' ','_').str.replace('.', '')

# and get the warning
FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
```

lastly, when we try

```
our_df.columns.str.replace(' ','_').str.replace('.', '').str.replace('+/-','plus_minus').str.lower()
```

...we get the error `nothing to repeat at position 0`.

1. Is it necessary to repeat `str.` between each `.replace()` call?
2. How can we resolve future warning?
3. The last error is caused by `.replace('+/-','plus_minus')` because there is no `+/-` in the columns. How can we handle this so that rather than throwing an error, it simply makes no replacements?
4. Am I doing this right?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2/3. `+` is a regex special character, you might want to escape it. 4. You can try turning index into a series and passing a dictionary `df.columns.to_series().replace({' ': '_', '.': ''}, regex=True)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If want use `str.replace` need repeat it, for `+` and `.` is necessary escape `\` because `regex special character`s and add `regex=True` for remove `future warning`:

```
(our_df.columns.str.replace(' ','_', regex=True)
               .str.replace('\.', '', regex=True)
               .str.replace('\+/-','plus_minus', regex=True)
               .str.lower())
```

Or if pass dictionary convert values to `Series`, because error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'replace'

---

```
c = ['Rank', 'Album', 'Artist', 'Label', 'Label Description',
       'Peak Position', 'Last Week Rank', 'Last 2 Week Rank', 'Weeks On Chart',
       'TW Total Activity', '% CHG', 'LW Total Activity', 'TW Album Sales',
       'TW Song Sales', 'TW TEA', 'TW Audio Streaming Activity',
       'TW Video Streaming Activity', 'TW Total SEA (Audio +/- Video)', 'ATD']
our_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c)

our_df.columns = our_df.columns.to_series().replace({'\s+':'_','\.': '','\+/-':'plus_minus'}, regex=True).str.lower()
print (our_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [rank, album, artist, label, label_description, peak_position, last_week_rank, last_2_week_rank, weeks_on_chart, tw_total_activity, %_chg, lw_total_activity, tw_album_sales, tw_song_sales, tw_tea, tw_audio_streaming_activity, tw_video_streaming_activity, tw_total_sea_(audio_plus_minus_video), atd]
Index: []
```

Comment: Really like the 2nd answer, thanks!